# Error in posterior function when running LDA

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to conduct topic modelling on a dataset. I follow standard procedure, clean the data, tokenize, create a dtm and apply the LDA function (topics <- tidy(my_topic_model, matrix = "beta"). When I try to use the posterior function (topics <- posterior(my_topic_model)$topics) I get the error: Error in UseMethod("posterior") :
no applicable method for 'posterior' applied to an object of class "c('LDA_Gibbs', 'LDA', 'Gibbs', 'TopicModel')".
I wasn't getting this initially when I was using this code, but when I tried to use it today it didn't work. I haven't changed anything in the code.

Can someone please help me out?